# How can I forcibly pass by value rust without deriving the Clone trait?

Tags: rust, glium

I'm new to rust and I'm trying to return a `Window` struct:

```rust
pub struct Window<'a> {
    ev_loop: EventLoop<()>,
    window_builder: WindowBuilder,
    context_builder: ContextBuilder<'a, NotCurrent>,
    display: Display
}
```

from this function:

```rust
pub fn init_lib () -> Window<'static> {
    let event_loop = glutin::event_loop::EventLoop::new();
    let wb = glutin::window::WindowBuilder::new();
    let cb = glutin::ContextBuilder::new();
    let display = glium::Display::new(wb, cb, &event_loop).unwrap();

    return Window {
        ev_loop: event_loop,
        window_builder: wb,
        context_builder: cb,
        display: display
    }
}
```

however whilst returning `wb` as `window_builder` and `cb` as `context_builder` I get the following error:

```
use of moved value: `cb`
value used here after moverustcE0382
lib.rs(32, 43): value moved here
lib.rs(31, 9): move occurs because `cb` has type `ContextBuilder<'_, NotCurrent>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I'm using `glium` which is a library, so I can't just modify the library code. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you really need to keep the Window _Builder_ and the Context _Builder_ after you've used them to build the `Display`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the solution to this siutation was to use reference `&`.

but since the `glium::Display::new()` doesnt accept references (see the [`docs`](https://docs.rs/glium/latest/glium/backend/glutin/struct.Display.html#method.new)), you need to clone the context builder aka `cb`.

look, `ContextBuilder` does `#[derive(Clone)]` in the [`source`](https://docs.rs/glutin/latest/src/glutin/lib.rs.html#93-99), so you can easily `.clone()` in your code.

sorry, but is how you can do things like that in rust, either you pass by reference or you clone it, if you dont want to `move` the object (aka lose the object)

this answer is for the case where you really want to keep context builder (`cb`) inside your `Window` struct

another bold solution (from what @Jmb suggested: `"Do you really need to keep the Window Builder and the Context Builder after you've used them to build the Display?"`) is to remove the `cb` field from `Window`.

good luck to your project!

Answer (score 0):

Answering to your question: you can use `core::ptr::read` to dereference pointer to a non-Copy value. Note that it’s unsafe and may cause double-free.

This is really not the best way, better take a look at what @alexzander said.